# Dynamically generate tabs and tables in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs, mat-table

I am trying to dynamically build the tabs and the tables under each of those tabs. I referred to this project for [dynamic tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377884/iterate-through-datasource-in-mat-table-angular) for the dynamic table.

This is my repo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-r6di58?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts

I am not really sure if the way I am passing the table data as an async stream is working. In my program, I have two tabs - Employee, Manager and each of the tabs has a table under it. Each table has its own sorter, pagination, and search. Search word is passed to the component.

[image]

Comment: Right away I see that you have are passing undefined values to the row and columns input for your app-table. I think instead of rowData you want rowData$. Even after that based on your structure, you would need to reference data.employees instead of trying to reference data[0] based on the looped index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are not passing the correct inputs to your component.

In `tab.component.html` you can use the `async` pipe to get the column and row arrays from your observables that your `app-table` component expects. Then, refer to each section using the tab name. You could use an index or enum instead, but your structure would need to support it.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{row: (rowData$ | async), col: (colData$ | async)} as data">
     <app-table [row]="data.row[tab.tabName]" [columns]="data.col[tab.tabName]" [search]='filters'>
     </app-table>
</ng-container>
```

Also, in `table.component.html` adding `*ngIf="dataSource"` to your `mat-table` tag will help clean up errors getting thrown before your `dataSource` is set.

I have some of your example working here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-klfdc5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab%2Ftab.component.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue .. do you know why the search is not working?

Comment: That is probably an issue with your ngOnChanges method. When your search input changes changes.data is undefined

Comment: Thank You that was the issue!